# Java Reflection Utility

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a utility to get a property which isnt prefixed by get from an object using reflection similar to BeanUtils? e.g. if I specify "hashCode" and I want to get the object.hashCode() value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `hashCode()` on every `Object`. You don't need reflection for this.

Otherwise, you can use the standard reflection classes - `java.lang.Class` and its method `getMethod(..)` which returns `java.lang.reflect.Method`.

Comment: @downvoter - could you please explain why this answer was not useful?

Answer (score 1):

The java reflection API allows you to access any property on a given instance of a class, including private variables.

Reflection is a powerful tool that allows you to do many things, including instantiating objects with private constructors.

Here is a decent tutorial for reflection that a quick google search turned up.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils was what I was looking for.

Comment: still, calling `hasCode()` is possible on every object, without reflection. If it is only for this method - just call it directly.

Comment: You cant call hashCode from JSF...nor size() etc

Answer (score 0):

**Finding Out About Class Fields**: It's possible to find out which data fields are defined in a class. To do this, the following code can be used:

```
   import java.lang.reflect.*;

   public class field1 {
      private double d;
      public static final int i = 37;
      String s = "testing";

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
         try {
            Class cls = Class.forName("field1");

            Field fieldlist[] 
              = cls.getDeclaredFields();
            for (int i 
              = 0; i < fieldlist.length; i++) {
               Field fld = fieldlist[i];
               System.out.println("name
                  = " + fld.getName());
               System.out.println("decl class = " +
                           fld.getDeclaringClass());
               System.out.println("type
                  = " + fld.getType());
               int mod = fld.getModifiers();
               System.out.println("modifiers = " +
                          Modifier.toString(mod));
               System.out.println("-----");
            }
          }
          catch (Throwable e) {
             System.err.println(e);
          }
       }
   }
```

source: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a utility to get a property which isn't prefixed by get from an object using reflection similar to BeanUtils?

There are the standard reflection APIs, but what you are asking for is problematic.  The Bean convention is that a method starting with `get` or `is` (and certain other characteristics) is a property.  Without this convention, it is not possible to know which of the methods of a class are property getters (or setters) and which are methods that have an entirely different purpose.  For example, you would NOT want to call `File.delete()` in the mistaken belief that it was a getter for some `boolean` property!!